# HTML5 Applications and Native Resources

Tags: android, iphone, ios, html

Can an HTML5 application that is running in a browser access native resources. The application would possibly be online or offline at any particular time.

For the sake of a specific example could javascript in the app access the camera and take a photo?

For this to be a viable option the answer would have to be yes for iphone and android.

Comment: This is a very broad question and there is no single right answer. The Android and iOS platforms differ enough that their answers won't even be the same. What is it you're trying to do? What's the specific task you need help with?

Comment: Have made the question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerometer and camera, currently (2011-01-08) no. Notifications, partially. GPS can be accessed with the `window.geolocation` object.

A product like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) allows almost full native access. It takes your HTML/Javascript apps, adds some hooks, and compiles to native for Android, iPhone and a few others.

There are also some hacks that install a tiny native iPhone app to do the camera access: [iphone-photo-picker](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/). Your web app can make a call to this app using a special URL. When finished it returns to your app.

Comment: OK, camera is a no. That would mean an online app is probably not viable for me. Any idea if this camera stuff will come and when?

Comment: @peter I think all hardware access will eventually be available, but camera access is probably way off.

Answer (score 2):

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) is a moble framework which supports accessing native features accelerometer,Camera,GPS and many other features for about 7 mobile OS(including iOS & android).It uses HTML,CSS,javascript.

Comment: Phonegap is one of my options, but this question is specifically related to an online application. If the answer to this question is no then I will have to use phonegap which will give me a native app, which is viable and will work for me.